# Run multiple sites on one code

Tags: php, .htaccess

We have a webcode which runs same site in 8 different countries.
However, we  do not disclose this information to the users.
Here's how we handle themes.
/httpdocs/themes/www.sitename.com/default/
and in htaccess, we skip www.sitename.com part with a RewriteRule and the user only sees,
/httpdocs/themes/default in his browser location.

This is working fine but the more sites we are adding, its become problematic when we need to create this environment on a Dev server and Local dev PCs.

How do we handle this address location problem. Its easier to remove the htaccess line and put everything in a config file but it strips us off a certain finesse we have achieved.

**Further Info**

Here's the htaccess rule.
`RewriteRule ^resources/image/(.*)$ resources/%{HTTP_HOST}/upload/image/$1 [L]`

Now on local, it becomes on folder, /resources/localsite/image whereas on live /resources/www.sitename.com/image.

Since we handle through the htacess therefore, the rule doesnt work on Local. The finesse I am talking about it is that the user/admin doesnt know we are wonderfully handling these sites in one code.

**Trying to write command in Vhost**

Wrote this command in vhost.conf create under Plesk.

```
<If "%{SERVER_NAME} = 'www.sitename.com'">
       SetEnv ThemePath www.sitename.com
</If>
```

but got the error.

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 23 of vhost.conf: Invalid command <If,
perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the  server configuration
```

Comment: Where's the problem when you need to create this environment on a Dev server and Local dev PCs?

Comment: What does " it strips us off a certain finesse we have achieved" mean?

Comment: Can you post your current .htaccess in your question?

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: use apache virtual host to set SERVER variables

Comment: @Oswald the dev server will have its own structure of files, although shared in the team while the developer himself may do his own vhost file on local and on live, the vhost is replaced with DNS.

Comment: @ajreal since these sites are clone of one site under plesk, so how do I go about creating these variables? I know it can be done with `SETENV`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the following in your Apache vhost configuration.  I haven't tested this in a .htaccess file, but I can't think of any obvious reason why this wouldn't work:

```
SetEnvIf HOST ^www.somesite.com$ NONWWWURL=1 
SetEnvIf HOST ^somesite.com$ NONWWWURL=0
```

I believe this should achieve what you are looking for.